# Running a node server in the background on travis

Tags: node.js, bash, mocha.js, travis-ci, chai

I'm trying to do unit tests on travis which require a node server which is located in a separate directory to run. So I need to have the server running in the background before I run the chai-mocha tests. But i've been having a lot of trouble getting it all to work... here is my .yml file

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6.10.0"
services: mongodb
env:
  - TEST_DIR=UserService/server
  - TEST_DIR=ApplicantService
  - TEST_DIR=ta-corrd-service
before_script:
  - sleep 15
script:
  - cd UserService/server && npm install nodemon && npm install && npm start& cd $TEST_DIR && npm install && npm test
```

I need to go into the userservice/server directory and then do an npm start and THEN do the npm test in each of the test_dir.

error i get on travis

```
> proj-awol@0.0.0 test /home/travis/build/csc302-2017-spring/proj-Awol/ta-corrd-service
> mocha --recursive
  course
(node:1780) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
    1) "before all" hook
  2) "after all" hook
  0 passing (68ms)
  2 failing
  1) course "before all" hook:
     Uncaught Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3002
      at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
      at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1087:14)
  2) course "after all" hook:
     Uncaught Error: socket hang up
      at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:254:15)
      at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:286:23)
      at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
The command "cd UserService/server && npm install nodemon && npm install && npm start& cd $TEST_DIR && npm install && npm test" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. When I do the commands on my machine it works...

edit: just some more info, that error message "ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED" happens on my local machine also if the node server is not running. So my guess is that travis isn't properly starting the node server. But i'm not sure whats wrong with my script.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, but what you are doing is making it tough for you. You should have all your tests in one directory. I can't think of a reason that would force you to keep your tests in different directories.

Whatever you want in your tests, can be easily imported using the `import`.

If you can figure that out, to run the server in the background from a different directory you could make use of a bash script with the following commands

```
cd path/to/directory
npm start &
```

Then in your .travis.yml file

```
script: 
 - ./your_script.sh
 - sleep 25
 - npm test
```